# How to bring an Activity to foreground (or create if not existing)?

Tags: android, android-activity, task, broadcast

I am intercepting sms messages with some information in them. Then in my SmsListener I'm creating notification to show in statusbar.
Then, when user clicks on a notification I want

1. Bring MainActivity to foreground (If such activity does not exist yet it should be created)
2. Pass to it data from the sms
3. Perform some ui changes basing on this data in this MainActivity

My activity is defined as

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Activity is launched as

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(i);
```

Also in my activity I have overridden method onNewActivity

```
 @Override
 public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // I have data from broadcast in intent variable passed to this activity
    processDataFromBroadcast(intent);
}
```

It works fine if the MainActivity already exists but if MainActivity does not exist it is started however onNewIntent was not called

Then I tried to invoke processDataFromBroadcast from onCreate: `processDataFromBroadcast(getIntent())`.
First time data is passed correctly from my broadcast to the activity.
However if MainActivity is sent to background and then again brought to foreground either onCreate or onNewIntent is called and processDataFromBroadcast is executed again with intent sent by broadcast and thus my MainActivity is updated with data from broadcast every-time the app is bringing to foreground - the latter is unwanted, how can I make my activity to forget this intent after first handling.
[Here is sample application.](http://www.box.net/shared/si6krushrv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an activity to launch only one instance of itself, have a look at the `<activity>` manifest element, and particularly `android:launchMode`. You want to configure it with either `singleTask` or `singleInstance`.

To pass data to your activity, you add data to the `Intent` you use to open it. To pass data with the intent, use the `putExtra()` methods of the intent before sending it off, and `getExtra()` methods to retrieve them in your receiving activity.

I'm assuming that you know roughly how intents work, but if not you could learn more about intents by taking a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) Android developers article.

Comment: Thanks for response. However please see my updates to the question.

Comment: Activity has the method getIntent() to retrieve the intent that triggered the activity. If you only want to process the intent on the first instantiation, you can do this from onCreate(). As you might know, onCreate() is only called when the activity is not already in memory.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I see I did not read your update properly as you have already tried this. I'm doing pretty much exactly what you are doing in one of my apps, and the only difference I can see right now is that I'm using the singleInstance launchmode, and have set android:alwaysRetainTaskState to true. My onCreate() is definitely not triggered when re-opening the activity.

Comment: And just to make sure.. you did remove the processDataFromBroadcast() call from onNewIntent() when you added it to onCreate()? :-)

Comment: No, processDataFromBroadcast is called in onCreate and onNewIntent, because when I receive broadcast notification and the MainActivity is not existing onNewInent is not called.
I guess in my case onCreate is triggered because my emulator has low resources and system kills the activity. When this occurs old intent getIntent() contains some data passed from broadcast last time and thus unwanted actions are performed during onCreate.
I also tried to modify intent by setIntent but it also does not work.

Comment: Do you exit the activity using the back button, btw? If so, the activity *will* be killed off and a new one will be created the next time. I also think onNewIntent() will be called whenever the activity is reopened, no matter if it is moved to the foreground by your intent or some other means. You might want to check the Intent type inside onNewIntent() and only run processDataFromBroadCast() if you can identify the intent as the one you are setting up manually.

Comment: Finally, if this does not do the trick, I would at least recommend adding some logging statements in onCreate() and onNewIntent() to see from which method processDataFromBroadcast() is really being triggered.

Comment: You are right rogerkk. onCreate was called only if I moved to back my act-ty by back button, otherwise onNewActivity is invoked - exactly as you wrote (and my last comment is little bit incorrect).
But old intent is passed to either onCreate or onNewIntent and this causes to execute processDataFromBroadcast() again, but I want processDataFromBroadcast was executed only once.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit slow here, I can't quite picture what is going on and I'm confusing what intents are being triggered. What do you mean by "old intent"? Could you maybe make a short use case so I understand the flow of things like they are now, and how you really would like them to be?

Comment: rogerkk - please, look at my last paragraph of question (It is updated)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I've been googling and experimenting, but I'm afraid I haven't found a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

in case your problem is still unresolved, as I was just running into the same issue, here's how I solved it:

I am putting a timestamp as intentId as an extra upon the intent during it's creation. the first time, I am handling the intent in `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()` I am reading the intentId and store it as the last intent handled. so the next time `onCreate()` or `onNewIntet()` is invoked I can check the intentId and if it equals the id of the last intent handled, I ignore it! It don't know if this helps in your case, maybe you can adopt it.

To keep intentId independent from activity lifecycles you could persist it in the userdefaults.

I agree that one would expect calling `setIntent(new Intent())` in `onNewIntent` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It it late to answer, but it might be helpful to others looking for the solution.

Just add below lines of code :

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // You need this if starting the activity from a service
mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Where SplashActivity is the name of initial application that is the first screen of your application.

Hope it helps. :)